# JS Infinite photo slider with several images on the same "window"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to figure out how would you build a photo slider where you have several photos in the sliding "window".

For example, I have 30 images and I would like to show 5 of them each time. When clicking on an arrow left/right - the next product will show and the other 4 will still be there.

So - 123[45678]9 after clicking left will be 12[34567]89 (where as the [] is the window).

After click an arrow I would like the new photo to slide in and an old photo to slide out the other side - and everything to to move in the direction. So it will look like it's just an infinite carousel.

Any nice ideas for making this simple and easy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out, I think this should fulfil your need

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

you can achieve the infinite scroll by using below mentioned code

```
<div class="multiple-items">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>

$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```